# Ler linhas e colunas pelo Python, pelo excel

Tags: python, microsoft-excel, lista, linha-de-comando

Minha duvida é se tem algum recurso para que eu consiga ler linhas e colunas do excel. Por exemplo: eu tenho dados experimentais no excel contendo cabeçalho na primeira linha tendo umas 12 colunas de dados, então [1:12] seria só o cabeçalho, e umas 30 linhas de dados numéricos, queria saber exatamente isso, como pega apenas dos dados dentro dessa matriz, e depois selecionar cada coluna e formar uma lista?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sim, existe [o pacote `xlrd`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlrd) que faz leituras de arquivos de Excel pra você.

Exemplo:

```
import xlrd
book = xlrd.open_workbook("meuarquivo.xls")
print "Número de abas: ", book.nsheets
print "Nomes das Planilhas:", book.sheet_names()
sh = book.sheet_by_index(0)
print(sh.name, sh.nrows, sh.ncols)
print("Valor da célula D30 é ", sh.cell_value(rowx=29, colx=3))
for rx in range(sh.nrows):
    print(sh.row(rx))
```

[Tirei o exemplo daqui](https://github.com/python-excel/xlrd).

[Veja também este site](http://www.python-excel.org/).

Comment: Por exemplo, nessa minha planilha no excel tem 7 paginas, antes eu teria que selecionar alguma, ou ele sempre pegará só a primeira?

Comment: Conforme o exemplo, você seleciona a página usando algo como `sh = book.sheet_by_index(0)`, onde `0` é o índice da página.

Comment: Tava meio perdido quanto a esse comando, agora ficou mais claro, pq sheet é pagina. Sou iniciante ai sempre perco essas pequenas coisas.

Comment: Fiz alguns testes, e me deu alguns resultados insatisfatorios. Primeiro porque eu não consigo selecionar por exemplo só a coluna 3 da planilha 3 e depois selecionar outra coluna, pois meu objetivo é selecionar esses dados excluindo o cabeçalho e formar uma nova lista, para então formar um grafico.

Comment: Bom, não existe mágica nisso. Te mostrei o começo do caminho. A pergunta não fala nada sobre gráficos. De qualquer forma, com alguma pesquisa e algum código escrito, você pode chegar numa pergunta que esteja mais próximo do que deseja.

Comment: Não, os graficos eu já sei fazer, o problema é selecionar os arquivos, se eu conseguir selecionar esses arquivos e colocar eles em forma de lista eu consigo fazer o grafico a partir desses dados. Porque do jeito que esta pelo menos, ta lendo tudo,lê ate os dados em branco.

Comment: Sim, pois como te falei, você queria uma resposta pra ler os dados do Excel. O refinamento da lógica não faz parte da pergunta. Isto é com você.